# Not able to execute all classes from Testng.xml, New connections will no longer be accepted

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Can someone help me out with below issue..!!!

I am trying to run all my packages from testng.xml file. it starts good but after execution of first package, it stop execution with error "Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted".
I searched a lot but not able to figure it out where is the actual problem.

Here is my Testng.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="example suite 1" verbose="1" >
    <test name="Login_Process" >
    <packages>
      <package name="Login_Process" />
      <package name="Demo" />

   </packages>   
 </test>
</suite>
```

Here is error logs

```
1500461044648   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:6073
1500461045318   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1500461045796   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1500461045797   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 < FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:674 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:837 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3145 < observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
1500461045799   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1657: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1500461049772   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 59593
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2572: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
Jul 19, 2017 6:44:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Lets Login!!
1500461064176   Marionette  INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted

===============================================
example suite 1
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 4
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 6
===============================================
```

Comment: it seems like there is a mismatch between firefox and geckdriver support. Would you please, downgrade the firefox few version and check if it's working.

Comment: @GaurangShah I have already checked that but still getting same issue. Do you know which version of Firefox and Gecko works perfectly ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Versions